# Mostrar datos de 1 tabla y su relacion con otra MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework

Buen dia compañeros tengo este Action Result en el controlador Productos que me busca todos los productos de un cierto IdEntrega y lo mando llamar desde la vista Entrega para saber todos los productos de esa entrega y funciona bien pero ahora necesito que ademas de aparecer todos los productos de esa entrega en la vista, tambien algunos datos de la entrega en la parte de arriba de la vista, como puedo hacerle?

```
public ActionResult Entrega(int id) 
{ 
var Productos = db.Productos.Where(d => e.IdEntrega==id).Include(p => 
p.Compra).Include(p => p.Empresa); 
return View(Productos.ToList()); 
} 

@Html.ActionLink("Detalles", "Entrega", "Productos", new { id = item.IdEntrega }, null)
```

Comment: Osea, quieres enviar mas datos ademas de los Productos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los ActionResult solo pueden enviar un solo modelo. Si quieres enviar mas 1 objeto entonces se utiliza el [`ViewBag`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M3VVHquF6K0) o un [`ViewModel`](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/e815f3bf-ce90-45dd-abed-ee75f680fc91/cuales-son-las-ventajas-de-tener-un-viewmodel-aparte-del-model-en-mvc?forum=aspnetmvces):

**ViewBag**: Son datos adicionales que pasas a las vistas ademas del modelo. Puedes enviar cuantas necesites y pueden ser de cualquier tipo ya que son del tipo `Dynamic`:

```
public ActionResult Entrega(int id) 
{ 
   var Productos = db.Productos.Where(d => e.IdEntrega==id).Include(p => 
    p.Compra).Include(p => p.Empresa); 

    ViewBag.Detalles = db.DetalesEntrega.Where( x=> x.EntregaId == id);
    return View(Productos.ToList()); 
}
```

Y para utilizar los valores en la vista

```
foreach(DetallesEntrega entrega in ViewBag.Detalles)
{
   <div>
        @entrega.Fecha
   </div>
}
```

**ViewModels**: En español: Modelo de la vista. Esto es una clase que *representa exactamente la vista*. Contiene todos los objetos que la vista requiere para funcionar:

```
public class EntregaViewModel
{
   public EntregaViewModel(List<Producto> productos, DetalleEntrega detalle)
   {
     this.Productos = productos;
     this.DetallesEntrega  = detalle;
   }

   public List<Producto> Productos {get; private set;}
   public DetalleEntrega Detalle {get; private set;}
}
```

`EntregaViewModel` representa los datos que el action resulta `Entrega` requiere. Entonces en vez de retornas los productos retornamos el viewmodel con los datos correspondientes:

```
public ActionResult Entrega(int id) 
    { 
       var Productos = db.Productos.Where(d => e.IdEntrega==id).Include(p => 
        p.Compra).Include(p => p.Empresa); 
        var detalles = db.DetalesEntrega.Where( x=> x.EntregaId == id);
        EntregaViewModel viewModel = new EntregaViewModel(Productos.ToList(), detalles);
        return View(viewModel); 
    }
```

Entonces en tu vista:

```
@model EntregaViewModel


    foreach(DetallesEntrega entrega in Model.Detalles)
    {
       <div>
            @entrega.Fecha
       </div>
    }

foreach(Producto producto in Model.Productos)
    {
       <div>
            @producto .Nombre
       </div>
    }
```

<sup><sub>Nota: Creo que estaria demas decir que esto es solo una guia. Cabe de ti adaptar el ejemplo a tus necesidades.</sub></sup>

Comment: Excelente guia compañero es justo lo que buscaba solo una una pregunta me sale error en el foreach(Entrega) me dice the type or namespace Entrega could not be found

Comment: Recuerda agregar las referencias de las clases que utilizas importando los namepace o utilizando using para que la vista pueda reconocer las clases. [La documentacion de microsoft tiene un tutorial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-3)  que te puede ayudar. Recuerda que solo fue un ejemplo, la parte de estructuracion de tu proyecto tendras que agregas ya que tu eres quien al conoce.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear un módelo que tenga los dos módelos.

```
public class MiModelo
{
    public List<Producto> Productos{ get; set; }
    public DetallesEntrega DetallesEntrega { get; set; }
}
```

Y en el controlador simplemente lo rellenas.

```
public ActionResult Entrega(int id) 
{ 
var Productos = db.Productos.Where(d => e.IdEntrega==id).Include(p => p.Compra).Include(p => p.Empresa); 

var miModelo = new MiModelo();
miModelo.Productos = Productos.ToList();
miModelo.DetallesEntrega = new DetallesEntrega();

return View(miModelo); 
}
```

No olvides declarar MiModelo en la vista.